# How to use google analytics real time data in google earth to get the viewing effect as on analytics page

Tags: windows, google-analytics, google-earth

I was trying to get the current viewers of the site and the cool location effect of the google earth plugin of Google Analytics on a full screen. I understand that Google Earth needs KML file, how do I get the realtime viewers data from Google Analytics and Display only the globe transition on a full screen.